# How to wrap <del></del> element around checkboxes with the values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was trying this code but it's not working please help , new to jquery

MY HTML

```
<div class="has-success topSpaceFromRoof">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSuccess" value="option1"> SAM C WILL HAVE BACON
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).click) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').wrapAll('<del></del>');
    }

});
```

Comment: What is `$(this).click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comments inline in the code below.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {

    // Check if checkbox is checked
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Disable checkbox

        var checkboxHtml = $(this).closest('label').html(); // Get the checkbox with the name of it

        $(this).closest('label').html('<del>' + checkboxHtml + '</del>'); // Wrap it in `del` tag
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qh6ahshj/)

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t4gknabn/9/)

**CODE**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {

    if($(this).is(":checked")){    
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').wrap('<del data-value='+$(this).attr("value")+'></del>');
    }


});
```